# Link not clickable on newer iPhones (3D Touch issue?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

I came across a problem:

I wrote a little quiz in HTML/CSS/JS. All works fine on desktop and android phones. But when I test it on newer iPhones, i have to press the answer for a little while to make the click work.

Is there any solution to make it normally clickable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's an <a> Element btw.

Comment: please show us the code you are using, otherwise no one can help you!

Comment: Can u share your code?